# WDS updating raid drivers in an already existing image WIM

Tags: windows, hp, imaging, wds, windows-pe

Here is my current setup.

- WDS installed on Server 2008 R2 for the new driverstore and multicast features.
- A Windows Server 2003 32bit Standard image built to support previous DL360 models.
- A new HP DL360 G6 which has a new raid controller in it.

I need to add the driver for the raid controller into my Server 2003 32bit standard install image but I can't seem to figure out the correct method to do so.

So far I've tried the following:

- Mounting the image and placing the drivers into the Sysprep drivers folder, adding the PCI device codes into the sysprep.inf file and committing the changes to the image.
- Pushing the image to a DL360 G4, ensuring the driver is in the correct locations and re-sysprepping the image.
- Hoping that the new driverstore feature would magically work with 2003 (a guy can dream cant he?)

Is there some standard method that I can use to update this image with the new drivers or do I need to start from scratch with an entirely new build?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What options are you providing to SysPrep? You may be telling it to remove all non-standard drivers if you Generalize.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this same issue and here's the basic steps of how to do it:

1. Mount the WIM file like this:

   `dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:<x:\img.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:<x:\mountPath>`
2. Add the driver:

   `dism /image:<x:\mountPath /Add-Driver:<x:\path\to\drivers> /Recurse`
3. Commit changes and unmount the WIM file:

   `dism /unmount-wim /mountDir:<x:\mountPath> /commit`

The easiest way to use the dism utility is to open the "Deployment Tools Command Prompt" from the Microsoft Windows AIK section of the start menu.

Also, in relation to adding drivers to the Sysprep.inf, I found a better way to do it is to use the spdrvscn.exe 3rd party utility to generate the registry entries directly instead of adding paths to the Sysprep.inf file (which get used to update the registry).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the DISM utility from the WAIK to inject drivers to the WIM file, or there's a gui to do that (check http://4sysops.com/archives/free-gdism-eldi-a-gui-for-managing-wim-images/ )